# Display SQL Server datetime in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

This can't be that freaking difficult. And before you flame me for not doing a simple search on the internet, I have spent the last four hours trying every possible solution I can find.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
$query3 = "SELECT  dbo.Job.Job, dbo.Job.Top_Lvl_Job, MIN(dbo.Delivery.Promised_Date) AS pd 
FROM dbo.Delivery INNER JOIN dbo.Job ON dbo.Delivery.Job = dbo.Job.Job 
GROUP BY dbo.Job.Job, dbo.Job.Top_Lvl_Job HAVING  (dbo.Job.Job = '" . $txtJob . "')";
$results3 = sqlsrv_query($connPpp, $query3);
$row3 = sqlsrv_fetch($results3);
$promised_date = $row3['pd'];
$promised_date = strtotime($promised_date);
?>
<h4>Promised Date: <?php echo date('n/d/y', $promised_date);?></h4>
```

This is what I get when I run it:

Promised Date: 12/31/69

If I manually run $Query3 through Sql Server Management Studio using this:

```
SELECT  dbo.Job.Job, dbo.Job.Top_Lvl_Job, MIN(dbo.Delivery.Promised_Date) AS Expr1 
FROM dbo.Delivery INNER JOIN dbo.Job ON dbo.Delivery.Job = dbo.Job.Job 
GROUP BY dbo.Job.Job, dbo.Job.Top_Lvl_Job HAVING  (dbo.Job.Job = '93450')
```

I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

So the data is there. If I try to echo $promised_date it returns nothing

Here is a screenshot from SQL Server showing the datatype:

[image: SQL Server]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is `$txtJob` defined? What does `$row3['pd']` and `$promised_date` (after strtotime) output?

Comment: The date 12/31/69 is the Unix Epoch. This means that strtotime($promised_date); is returning 0. What happens when you echo both $promised_date and strtotime($promised_date)? I'm suspecting either strtotime isn't parsing your date correctly, or your date is being incorrectly fetched.

Comment: If I echo $query3 I get:

SELECT dbo.Job.Job, dbo.Job.Top_Lvl_Job, MIN(dbo.Delivery.Promised_Date) AS pd FROM dbo.Delivery INNER JOIN dbo.Job ON dbo.Delivery.Job = dbo.Job.Job GROUP BY dbo.Job.Job, dbo.Job.Top_Lvl_Job HAVING (dbo.Job.Job = '94875')

Comment: If I copy the same line from the echo $query3 into Sql Server Management studio it returns the data. That is why I'm confused why echo $row3['pd'] does not return anything.

Comment: If I switch sqlsrv_fetch to sqlsrv_fetch_array I get this error:
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string. 
This error is referencing $promised_date = strtotime($promised_date);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed from sqlsrv_fetch to sqlsrv_fetch_array, dumped the strtotime and did this:

```
<?php echo date_format($promised_date, 'n/d/y');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is really working, and `echo $row3['pd']` shows the same date as you see in Management Studio (ie `2016-04-18 00:00:00.000`), my guess would be that strtotime() doesn't like seconds with 3 decimal points.  If you don't really track down to thousands of a second and the decimals will always be 000, you could try:

```
$promised_date = strtotime(str_replace('.000', '', $promised_date));
```

If the decimals might be real fractional seconds like .123, maybe something like this (assuming those 3 decimals will always be there of course):

```
$promised_date = strtotime(substr($promised_date, 0, -4));
```